# "display: contents" alternative

Tags: html, css

Or how do I mix semantic HTML and layout.

I would like to do something like:

```
<ul>
  <li class="name">Bob
     <ul class="details">
        <li>long stuff here, wow so long</li>
        <li>col 1</li>
     </ul>
  <li>
  <li class="name">Jerry
     <ul class="details">
        <li>short</li>
        <li>col 1</li>
     </ul>
  <li>
```

I would this laid out like a table where items in the `details`, regardless of their width, line up vertically. However, I would also like to maintain the `<ul>` for semantic purposes. Until `display: contents` is widely available, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Nope. That's why display contents exists.

Comment: Can you show an example of how you would achieve the desired result with `display: contents`? I’m not sure exactly what you mean.

Comment: display: contents has a already a good coverage: https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents. All the major browser support it